# unresolved traceback using selenium webdriver in python3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried using this Python module but I receive this traceback and can not for the life of me figure out how to solve it. I tried to download different geckodriver,firefox, selenium. I am running this on a ubuntu machine in the interactive shell. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> > > from selenium import webdriver
> > >       browser = webdriver.Firefox()
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >             File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver       /firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in **init**
> > >               keep_alive=True)
> > >             File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in **init**
> > >           self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> > >             File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in start_session
> > >           response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
> > >             File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
> > >           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> > >             File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
> > >           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> > >           selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: Do you have the versions of Ubuntu, Selenium, browser, and webdriver that we could see?

Comment: geckodriver --version
geckodriver 0.20.0

The source code of this program is available from
testing/geckodriver in https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central.

This program is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0.
You can obtain a copy of the license at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

Comment: PACKAGE CONTENTS
    common (package)
    webdriver (package)

VERSION
    3.8.0

FILE
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/__init__.py

Comment: o LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: $ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 60.0

Comment: This last comment is the version of the webdriver

Comment: VERSION
    3.9.0

FILE
    /home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py

Comment: Find out which directory your geckdrive located, and add the directory to your python code like this `browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')`